# Flutter: implementing permission handler at the start of screen

Tags: flutter

Permission_handler.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:permission_handler/permission_handler.dart';
import 'package:status_saver/utils/splash_screen.dart';

class PermissionHandler extends StatefulWidget {
  const PermissionHandler({ Key? key }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _PermissionHandlerState createState() => _PermissionHandlerState();
}

class _PermissionHandlerState extends State<PermissionHandler> {
  Future<Widget> permissionCheck() async {
    var permissionStatus = await Permission.storage.status;


    if (!permissionStatus.isGranted){
      await Permission.storage.request();

    }
     permissionStatus = await Permission.storage.status;
     if(permissionStatus.isGranted) return SplashScreen();
     else {
          return AlertDialog(
              title: Text('Permission Required'),  // To display the title it is optional
              content: Text('Cannot proceed without permission'),   // Message which will be pop up on the screen
              // Action widget which will provide the user to acknowledge the choice
                actions: [
                TextButton(           // FlatButton widget is used to make a text to work like a button
                  child: Text('Open App Settings'),
                  onPressed: () => openAppSettings(),   
                       // function used to perform after pressing the button
                ),
                
              ],
            );
            
     }
     
  }
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder(
          builder: (ctx, snapshot) {
            
            // Checking if future is resolved or not
            if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
              // If we got an error
               
              if (snapshot.hasError) {
                return Center(
                  child: Text(
                    '${snapshot.error} occured',
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18),
                  ),
                );
  
                // if we got our data
              } else  {
                return snapshot.data as Widget;
              }
            }
  
            // Displaying LoadingSpinner to indicate waiting state
            return Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            );
          },
  
          // Future that needs to be resolved
          // inorder to display something on the Canvas
          future: permissionCheck(),
        );
  }
}
```

Main.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:status_saver/services/permission_handler.dart';
import 'package:status_saver/utils/router.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GetMaterialApp(
      title: 'Hello World',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      onGenerateRoute: AppRouter.generateRoute,
      theme: ThemeData(
        // This is the theme of your application.
        //
        // Try running your application with "flutter run". You'll see the
        // application has a blue toolbar. Then, without quitting the app, try
        // changing the primarySwatch below to Colors.green and then invoke
        // "hot reload" (press "r" in the console where you ran "flutter run",
        // or simply save your changes to "hot reload" in a Flutter IDE).
        // Notice that the counter didn't reset back to zero; the application
        // is not restarted.
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: PermissionHandler(),
    );
  }
}
```

### scenario

1. At the start of the app i want to ask for storage permission
   What i did - create class `PermissionHandler` and assign it to `home` attribute
2. PermissionHandler() - stateful widget, shall trigger splashscreen after finishing its business logic

#### expected behaviour

- Ask user permission until user grants it
- if user grants permission. directly trigger splash screen instead of permission handler screen ( adds black screen and then splash screen currently as permission check code is ran everytime app starts)
  *if user clicks on `dont ask again` take user to app settings and check again if permission is granted or not

#### current behaviour

- ask for permission at start of the app for single time, if accepted it loads splash screen else a new dialogue is popped up which takes user to appsettings
- after giving permission from appsettings when user comesback to app code is unable to check permission is granted or not and nothing happens further (problem)
- if i ask for permssion until user grants it using while loop. if user denies permission by clicking on  `dont ask agin` checkbox, while loop will keep requesting for permission but dialogue will not present (current behaviour of permission_handler) which leads to infite loop and nothing will happen further
- after permission is granted. if user comes back to app Future builder still execute following code and then triggers splashscreen instead directly triggering splash screen. (Bad UI experience)

```
 return Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            );
```

## Problem 1

```
 [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(PermissionHandler.PermissionManager, A request for permissions is
already running, please wait for it to finish before doing another request (note that you can request multiple permissions at the same time)., null, null)
[        ] E/flutter (  787): #0      StandardMethodCodec.decodeEnvelope (package:flutter/src/services/message_codecs.dart:607:7)
[        ] E/flutter (  787): #1      MethodChannel._invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:156:18)
[        ] E/flutter (  787): <asynchronous suspension>
[        ] E/flutter (  787): #2      MethodChannelPermissionHandler.requestPermissions
(package:permission_handler_platform_interface/src/method_channel/method_channel_permission_handler.dart:71:9)
[        ] E/flutter (  787): <asynchronous suspension>
[        ] E/flutter (  787): #3      _PermissionHandlerScreenState.permissionServices (package:status_saver/services/permission_handler.dart:38:50)
[        ] E/flutter (  787): <asynchronous suspension>
[        ] E/flutter (  787): #4      _PermissionHandlerScreenState.permissionServiceCall (package:status_saver/services/permission_handler.dart:19:5)
[        ] E/flutter (  787): <asynchronous suspension>
[        ] E/flutter (  787):
```

error is thrown when I press deny button

### problem 2

after giving permissions from app settings
error is thrown:  `no permissions defined in the manifest for: []`

manifest files have storage permissions defined,(I removed code for camera , and microphone for easy testing so not a problem about them)

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please refer to below example code

Solution 1: Users are restricted to navigating to any other routes/screens without allowing all the permissions mentioned

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  MyApp({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primaryColor: Color(0xfff00B074),
        textTheme: const TextTheme(
          bodyText1: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 18.0,
              fontFamily: 'Barlow-Medium',
              color: Color(0xff464255)),
        ),
      ),
      home: PermissionHandlerScreen(),
    );
  }
}

class PermissionHandlerScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _PermissionHandlerScreenState createState() =>
      _PermissionHandlerScreenState();
}

class _PermissionHandlerScreenState extends State<PermissionHandlerScreen> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    permissionServiceCall();
  }

  permissionServiceCall() async {
    await permissionServices().then(
      (value) {
        if (value != null) {
          if (value[Permission.storage].isGranted &&
              value[Permission.camera].isGranted &&
              value[Permission.microphone].isGranted) {
            /* ========= New Screen Added  ============= */

            Navigator.pushReplacement(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SplashScreen()),
            );
          }
        }
      },
    );
  }

  /*Permission services*/
  Future<Map<Permission, PermissionStatus>> permissionServices() async {
    // You can request multiple permissions at once.
    Map<Permission, PermissionStatus> statuses = await [
      Permission.storage,
      Permission.camera,
      Permission.microphone,
      //add more permission to request here.
    ].request();

    if (statuses[Permission.storage].isPermanentlyDenied) {
      await openAppSettings().then(
        (value) async {
          if (value) {
            if (await Permission.storage.status.isPermanentlyDenied == true &&
                await Permission.storage.status.isGranted == false) {
              openAppSettings();
              // permissionServiceCall(); /* opens app settings until permission is granted */
            }
          }
        },
      );
    } else {
      if (statuses[Permission.storage].isDenied) {
        permissionServiceCall();
      }
    }
    if (statuses[Permission.microphone].isPermanentlyDenied) {
     await openAppSettings().then(
        (value) async {
          if (value) {
            if (await Permission.microphone.status.isPermanentlyDenied == true &&
                await Permission.microphone.status.isGranted == false) {
              openAppSettings();
              // permissionServiceCall(); /* opens app settings until permission is granted */
            }
          }
        },
      );
    } else {
      if (statuses[Permission.microphone].isDenied) {
        permissionServiceCall();
        
      }
    }

    if (statuses[Permission.camera].isPermanentlyDenied) {
await openAppSettings().then(
        (value) async {
          if (value) {
            if (await Permission.camera.status.isPermanentlyDenied == true &&
                await Permission.camera.status.isGranted == false) {
              openAppSettings();
              // permissionServiceCall(); /* opens app settings until permission is granted */
            }
          }
        },
      );
      //openAppSettings();
      //setState(() {});
    } else {
      if (statuses[Permission.camera].isDenied) {
        permissionServiceCall();
      }
    }
    /*{Permission.camera: PermissionStatus.granted, Permission.storage: PermissionStatus.granted}*/
    return statuses;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    permissionServiceCall();
    return WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: () {
        SystemNavigator.pop();
      },
      child: Scaffold(
        body: Container(
          child: Center(
            child: InkWell(
                onTap: () {
                  permissionServiceCall();
                },
                child: Text("Click here to enable Enable Permission Screen")),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class SplashScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const SplashScreen({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: () {
        SystemNavigator.pop();
      },
      child: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: Text(
            "Splash Screen",
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Solution 2:

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  MyApp({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primaryColor: Color(0xfff00B074),
        textTheme: const TextTheme(
          bodyText1: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 18.0,
              fontFamily: 'Barlow-Medium',
              color: Color(0xff464255)),
        ),
      ),
      home: PermissionHandlerScreen(),
    );
  }
}

class PermissionHandlerScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _PermissionHandlerScreenState createState() =>
      _PermissionHandlerScreenState();
}

class _PermissionHandlerScreenState extends State<PermissionHandlerScreen> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    permissionServiceCall();
  }

  permissionServiceCall() async {
    await permissionServices().then(
      (value) {
        if (value != null) {
          if (value[Permission.storage].isGranted &&
              value[Permission.camera].isGranted &&
              value[Permission.microphone].isGranted) {
            /* ========= New Screen Added  ============= */

            Navigator.pushReplacement(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SplashScreen()),
            );
          }
        }
      },
    );
  }

  /*Permission services*/
  Future<Map<Permission, PermissionStatus>> permissionServices() async {
    // You can request multiple permissions at once.
    Map<Permission, PermissionStatus> statuses = await [
      Permission.storage,
      Permission.camera,
      Permission.microphone,
      //add more permission to request here.
    ].request();

    if (statuses[Permission.storage].isPermanentlyDenied) {
      openAppSettings();
      //setState(() {});
    } else {
      if (statuses[Permission.storage].isDenied) {
        permissionServiceCall();
      }
    }
    if (statuses[Permission.microphone].isPermanentlyDenied) {
      openAppSettings();
     // setState(() {});
    } else {
      if (statuses[Permission.microphone].isDenied) {
        permissionServiceCall();
        
      }
    }

    if (statuses[Permission.camera].isPermanentlyDenied) {
      openAppSettings();
      // setState(() {});
    } else {
      if (statuses[Permission.camera].isDenied) {
        permissionServiceCall();
      }
    }
    /*{Permission.camera: PermissionStatus.granted, Permission.storage: PermissionStatus.granted}*/
    return statuses;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    
    return WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: () {
        SystemNavigator.pop();
      },
      child: Scaffold(
        body: Container(
          child: Center(
            child: InkWell(
                onTap: () {
                  permissionServiceCall();
                },
                child: Text("Click here to enable Enable Permissions")),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class SplashScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const SplashScreen({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: () {
        SystemNavigator.pop();
      },
      child: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: Text(
            "Splash Screen",
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: use of setState in isPermissionDenied makes future run forever and app keeps on switching between app settings and app

Comment: In order to restrict users from navigating to any screen further without permission, I have called the function again and again. If you are fine with allowing users to navigate to other screens without permission we can remove setState and function call in start of build method

Comment: Please try above updated code

Comment: I don't want the user to go to another screen, behaviour you created in solution 1 is right but when permission is permanently denied,  in an automated way screen is just switching between app and settings.

Comment: Yeah that I have fixed in Solution 2. Please try that and let me know if that is what you are expecting

Comment: Edited the post , about the problems in second solution

Comment: Yes I have edited in the second solution. Please try

Comment: Yeah, it works fine, but after setting permission from settings, and coming back to the app the same screen is present, it doesn't reroute to the splash screen. I have to refresh it. also WillPopScope() needs to return something I am currently returning Future.value(true)

Comment: In place of setstate you can add Navigator.pop to navigate to the splash screen. But after permission granted only you need to allow the user to navigate to splash screen right until then they have to stay in Permission Handler Screen

Comment: Yes, that is what I am willing to do, how pop instead of set state will work we have only one route present in the navigation stack. if I grant permission through app settings and comeback it's just popping the current permission handler screen and returning black screen

Comment: I am sorry I am bit confused. I think calling permissionServiceCall function in place of setstate to check whether all the permissions are granted may help you

Comment: Your code is perfectly fine, just it can't handle it when the user permanently denies the request.

we cant call permissionServiceCall , it will run forever, "if user click don't ask again" then permanently denies state is triggered and we will not have any dialog where user can change permission onwards, so permissionServiceCall just rerender forever and nothing will happen

Comment: Okay, I will check and update you on the same

Comment: I checked this , after clicking on don't ask again status will still be denied only we have to check in different way for don't ask again 

https://github.com/Baseflow/flutter-permission-handler/issues/96
https://github.com/Baseflow/flutter-permission-handler/wiki/Changes-in-6.0.0#breaking-changes

and this is why when don't ask again is clicked permanently denied is not called instead whole function is repeatedly called and nothing happens

Comment: Please check Solution1  for these code changes `await openAppSettings().then(
        (value) async {
          if (value) {
            if (await Permission.storage.status.isPermanentlyDenied == true &&
                await Permission.storage.status.isGranted == false) {
              openAppSettings();
              // permissionServiceCall(); /* opens app settings until permission is granted */
            }
          }
        },
      );
` Please try ant let me know if it is working fine